# SQL Server date comparisons based on month and year only

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, date

I am having trouble determining the best way to compare dates in SQL based on month and year only.

We do calculations based on dates and since billing occurs on a monthly basis the date of the month has caused more hindrance.

For example

```
DECLARE @date1 DATETIME = CAST('6/15/2014' AS DATETIME),
        @date2 DATETIME = CAST('6/14/2014' AS DATETIME)

SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE @date1 <= @date2
```

The above example would not return any rows since @date1 is greater than @date2. So I would like to find a way to take the day out of the equation.

Similarly, the following situation gives me grief for same reason.

```
DECLARE @date1 DATETIME = CAST('6/14/2014' AS DATETIME),
        @date2 DATETIME = CAST('6/15/2014' AS DATETIME),
        @date3 DATETIME = CAST('7/1/2014' AS DATETIME)

SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE @date2 BETWEEN @date1 AND @date3
```

I've done inline conversions of the dates to derive the first day and last day of the month for the date specified.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableName 
WHERE date2 BETWEEN
    DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, date1), 0) -- The first day of the month for date1
    AND
    DATEADD(s, -1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0, date2) + 1, 0)) -- The lastday of the month for date3
```

There has to be an easier way to do this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Which version of SQL Server?

Comment: @christiandev We are using SQL 2008.

Comment: As a side note, If you aren't using the time part, you can use `DATE` data type.

Comment: Thanks @davidg - just read the new code of conduct proposed on meta and thought getting dinged was rather interesting.

Comment: What is the `WHERE @date2 BETWEEN @date1 AND @date3` supposed to do? I guess you meant `date2` to be a column and not a variable?

Comment: You might want to have a look at this: **[Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)**

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To handle inequalities, such as between, I like to convert date/times to a YYYYMM representation, either as a string or an integer.  For this example:

```
DECLARE @date1 DATETIME = CAST('6/14/2014' AS DATETIME),
        @date2 DATETIME = CAST('6/15/2014' AS DATETIME),
        @date3 DATETIME = CAST('7/1/2014' AS DATETIME);

SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE @date2 BETWEEN @date1 AND @date3;
```

I would write the query as:

```
SELECT *
FROM tableName
WHERE year(@date2) * 100 + month(@date2) BETWEEN year(@date1) * 100 + month(@date1) AND
                                                 year(@date3) * 100 + month(@date1);
```

Comment: Here, are you just calculating the number of days to compare, that is the only reason to multiply it by 100 ?

Comment: @Sak . . . It is comparing months in the YYYYMM format.  This is a convenient method for generating a number in that format.

Answer (score 26):

You can filter the month and year of a given date to the current date like so:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableName 
WHERE month(date2) = month(getdate()) and year(date2) = year(getdate())
```

Just replace the `GETDATE()` method with your desired date.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but that doesn't address the date ranges.  For example 'WHERE date1 BETWEEN date2 AND date3'

Comment: @AndyEvans so you want all records where the date falls within a single month of a year?

Comment: What I am looking for is (for example) are all records from 6/x/2013 to 11/x/2014 - regardless of day of the month.

Answer (score 14):

You can join on [`MONTH`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms187813.aspx) and [`YEAR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms186313.aspx) values of those dates:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableName 
WHERE YEAR(@date1) = YEAR(@date2) AND MONTH(@date1) = MONTH(@date2)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but that doesn't address the date ranges.  For example 'WHERE date1 BETWEEN date2 AND date3'

Comment: @AndyEvans Rolled back my edit, on second thoughts for ranges better to use the answer from GordonLinoff.

Answer (score 8):

First, I'd use a format for the dates that is unambiguous, like the standard `'YYYYMMDD'` and not the `'6/15/2014'` you have been using. Aaron Bertrand's blog explains far better than I could, the various ways this can go wrong:
 **[Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)**

For the specific problem, your last query which finds the first and the last days of the months (for date1 and date3), is in my opinion on the right track. You only need though the first days of months (first day of date1 and first day of next month for date3), if you avoid the *evil `BETWEEN`*:  **[What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)**

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableName 
WHERE date2 >= DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, '19000101', @date1), '19000101')
  AND date2 < DATEADD(month, 1+DATEDIFF(month, '19000101', @date3), '19000101') ;
```

The query works as it is, no matter the datatype of `date2` (`DATE`, `DATETIME`, `DATETIME2` or `SMALLDATTEIME`).

Bonus point, indexes on `date2` will be considered by the optimizer this way.

---

Improvement, according to (yet, another) Aaron's blog post, to avoid a problem with cardinality estimation when evaluating expressions with `DATEDIFF()`:
 **[Performance Surprises and Assumptions : DATEDIFF](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/09/t-sql-queries/datediff-bug)**

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableName 
WHERE date2 >= CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(day, 1 - DAY(@date1), @date1))
  AND date2 < DATEADD(month, 1, 
                      CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(day, 1 - DAY(@date3), @date3))) ;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use formatting your date like this 'yyyyMM' , so only the month in the same year will be selected.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableName 
WHERE FORMAT(date_month_bill, 'yyyyMM') < FORMAT(DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE()), 'yyyyMM') 
AND FORMAT(date_month_bill, 'yyyyMM') > FORMAT(DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE()), 'yyyyMM')
```

Comment: Honestly think this is the best solution for the problem. You can handle all cases using this format for year and month

Answer (score 2):

I rolled my dates up to the same date using EOMONTH() and compared them. So, if I had date1 as 09/18/2019 and date2 as 09/16/2019 they would both roll up to 09/30/2019. It isn't a direct answer to your question, but it worked in my situation.

Answer (score 2):

This is a classic math problem. Its easy to compare months with months. That is multiply year with number of months in a year and add month of the year to it. This will give an integer which can be compared in a range.

Ex: July 2021 would be 07+12*2021