# How to select record for any date in given month

Tags: sql-server

I have a table which is storing salary slip record along with the date it was created. By default I want to show the current month's records.

I want to find all records from the current month. Some slips might be generated on 1st of month some on 10th but it should show all rows of the given month.

```
SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()),MONTH(GETDATE()),1)
```

I'm using this statement to get the records that were stored in table on the first date of this month but what about the records saved on 2nd or 3rd and so on?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server date comparisons based on month and year only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26239784/sql-server-date-comparisons-based-on-month-and-year-only)

Comment: This should help you get what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26239895/57475

Comment: Why do you show your `select` clause? If you want certain records, it's your `where` clause you should show.

Answer (score 0):

Try using where condition

```
 where YEAR(date_column)=YEAR(GETDATE()) and MONTH(date_column)=MONTH(GETDATE())
```

Comment: I don't understand the downvote either.I think this is the straight-forward approach to select a given month's records.

Comment: Thanks @Thorsten Kettner

Comment: functions around the column names in the where clause will hamper the performance as they will lead to scanning the entire table.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution-

```
declare @tbl table (Slipdate datetime)

insert into @tbl (Slipdate)
select '2018-02-01'
union
select '2018-02-23'
union
select '2018-01-01'

select *
from @tbl
where dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,Slipdate),0) = dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,GETDATE()),0)
```